# Loop through datatable to create json in web api

Tags: api, web

I am trying to create a JSON response from the WebServices that return a dataset. How can I loop through the datatable and put those values in client model? When I try to loop through the datatable I get invalid initiater error.
Here is my code:

```
public class ClientsController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<ClientResponseModels> GetAllClients()
    {  
        //retrieves list of all the clients
        var dsClients = ClientRepository.GetAllClients();

        //create a json response object
        ClientResponseModels[] response = new ClientResponseModels[]
        {
            new ClientResponseModels
            {
                UserId= userDetails.UserID,
                UserName=userDetails.LoginName,
                LocationName=centreLocation.ToString(),
                Clients = new List<ClientModels>
                {  
                    foreach(DataRow row in dsClients.Tables[0].rows)
                    {
                        new ClientModels //these values need to come from datatable
                        {
                            Id =Convert.ToInt32(row["client_id"]), 
                            ClientName=Convert.ToString(row["client_nme"])", 
                            DOB= Convert.ToDateTime(row["birth_date]")
                        }
                    }    
                } 
            }
        };
        return response;
    }
    else {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I you use entity framework change datacontext configuration.

```
        MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();
        db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the function is the cause as your code I'd looping through a queryable. You can retrieve the data first before looping e.g.  GetAllClients().ToList()